# Xamarin.Forms in F# Interactive

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, fsi

By referencing the default WPF DLLs, it's pretty easy to do anything you could do using code-only WPF:

```
#r "Accessibility.dll"
#r "PresentationCore.dll"
#r "PresentationFramework.dll"
#r "System.Core.dll"
#r "System.Data.dll"
#r "System.dll"
#r "System.Drawing.dll"
#r "System.Numerics.dll"
#r "System.Xaml.dll"
#r "System.Xml.dll"
#r "UIAutomationProvider.dll"
#r "UIAutomationTypes.dll"
#r "WindowsBase.dll"

let window = System.Windows.Window()
let panel = System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel()
let button = System.Windows.Controls.Button()
panel.Children.Add button
button.Content <- "hi"

window.Content <- panel

window.Show()
```

... and you can manipulate it while the window is still open...

```
button.Click.Add (fun _ ->
    button.Content <-
        button.Content :?> string |> fun x -> (x + "!") :> obj)
```

...and then click the button to see it work. It seems like a pretty powerful way to build up UI components.

**Is there any way to do the same thing with Xamarin.Forms?**

Comment: Have you tried this?  I would assume that it should work just fine

Comment: "This" what? Xamarin.Forms doesn't have the concept of a Window, so it needs some kind of host on a given platform, and just throwing it in a System.Windows.Window doesn't work.

Comment: Not a xamarin expert but I would assume that the same base scaffolding you would normally use should work